# Eclipse and Node.Js debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging, node.js, automation, command-line-arguments

I learned how to [debug node.js with Eclipse](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger), but how can I automate the following process:

- I press `debug`
- It runs the comand `node --debug app.js`

I could not find how to do so in Eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [snippet](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqMxaETAMaA) or a [plugin](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-plugindev2/) to consolidate the commands into a single button press and eliminate the tedium.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following plug-ins, you'll be able to easily debug Node Application with Eclipse.

http://www.tomotaro1065.com/nodeclipse/