# History, etc. of Nodeclipse & Enide

Tags: nodeclipse, joyent, enide

I'm an experience-zero Japanese newbie for Nodeclipse & Enide. Could anyone answer my questions below? I can't find anything related to them inside Nodeclipse & Enide homepage:

1. What is the difference between Nodeclipse and Enide?
2. When and for what did Nodeclipse community (or Joyent) raise Enide?

Thank you in advance.

Fujio Nakano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if its appropriate question for `stackoverflow` or not but i am answering for your understanding!

`NodeEclipse` is a Node.js development plugin for `Eclipse IDE` while `Enide` is a full IDE based on `Eclipse` and `NodeEclipse`. So if you install `Enide` it feels like you are using `Eclipse` may be thats why you got confused!

Answer (score 1):

As Nodeclipse author I can tell that

Nodeclipse was started at Lamb Gao from China,
then Tomoyuki Inagaki from Japan integrated debugging (see [Eclipse and Node.Js debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159238/eclipse-and-node-js-debugging)) and did few more releases with small contribution from Paul Verest.
And after Tomoyuki went into non responsive state, Paul Verest(me) continued and for much longer time.

Initially Enide, was .p2f file to quickly install Nodeclipse together with some other found related plugins: like Markdown. Then I used Enide for something broader then Nodeclipse: general tools and tools for Java, full standalone Eclipse IDE packages as Enide Studio.
While using Nodeclipse for Node.js tools and organization name.

There is http://www.nodeclipse.org/history page that link to some issues, but all has been public in https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1 issues.

You can change the website as you would like by just making change to https://github.com/nodeclipse/www.nodeclipse.org